# How do I store a text file into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, user-input

I am trying to open a text file inputted by the user and read this text file but print the text file 60 characters at a time so I think in order for me to do this I need to store the text into an array and if it is over 60 characters on a line it should start on a new line. However, when I run the code below an error message shows up saying : C^@

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
char arr[]; 
arr[count] = '\0';
char ch, file_name[25];
FILE *fp;

printf("Enter file name: \n");
gets(file_name);

fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // reading the file

if( fp == NULL )
{
   perror("This file does not exist\n"); //if file cannot be found print       error message
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
arr[count] = ch;
count++;
  printf("%s", arr);}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing braces to delimit the `while` block. `count` is uninitialized when you start adding items to the array. You do nothing to check if `count` is under 60. In other words, the most important parts of your code will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Stop trying to develop software until you know how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char arr[];` is invalid.you need to specify a size.

`array[count] = '\0';` : count is uninitialized.

`gets(file_name);` : gets is deprecated and dangerous.use another function like scanf.

Try the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ch , count = 0;
    char file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter file name: \n");
    scanf(" %24s",file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // reading the file

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror("This file does not exist\n"); //if file cannot be found print       error message
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char arr[sz];

    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        if( count < sz )
        {
            arr[count] = ch;
            count++;
        }
    }
    arr[sz] = '\0';
    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
    printf("arr : %s\n",arr);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it says an error on the penultimate print statement: expected delcaration or statement expected after input

Answer (score 0):

**fgetc** always reads the next character until **EOF**. use **fgets()** instead:

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)

fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and 
stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF 
or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A 
terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the 
buffer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. The variable `count` is not initialized, so it's value is indeterminate and using it will lead to *undefined behavior*.
2. The call `printf(arr)` treats `arr` as a string but `arr` is not terminated which again leads to *undefined behavior*.
3. The increment of `count` is *outside* the loop.

To solve the two first problems you must first initialize `count` to zero, then you must terminate the string after the loop:

```
arr[count] = '\0';
```

However, your `printf(arr)` call is still *very* problematic, what if the user enters some `printf` formatting codes, what will happen then? That's why you should *never* call `printf` with a user-provided input string, instead simply do

```
printf("%s", arr);
```

You also have a very big problem if the contents of the file you read is longer than 59 characters, and then you will overflow the array.

Comment: He neads to break the lines when they are longer than 60 chars.

Answer (score 0):

1) your `while` loop is not properly delimited. In the absence of a `{  }` block, the instruction `arr[count] = ch;` is the only repeted one.

I suppose it should include the incrementation of `count` too

```
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
  {
     arr[count] = ch;
     count++;
     ....
  }
```

among other things (testing the counter etc).

2) there's no imperative need to read and store in an array. It is perfectly possible to transfer each character as soon as it is read, and add a line break when needed (new line, limit of 60 exceeded).

Comment: so is there an easier way rather than me adding the characters into an array, to limit the characters to 60 each line, and if a word is not going to fit into that 60 line limit it should start on a new line

Comment: If you add the requirement "word fitting on the 60-chars line", the answer is no, becauseyou have to read the entire word before deciding whether you'll break the line or not. And so you have to store it somewhere.
But you modified the requirements. There is more about it : what happen to the spaces before a word whan you decide to put it on the next line?